# How to Automatically scale up/down workers?

Tags: c#, multithreading, scalability, worker

How to auto scale worker tasks?

I have an application which I want to automatically scale the number of worker tasks to accommodate for the throughput of items to process (with a maximum limit to the number of workers obviously).

All items to process are routed through a single point, from which they are distributed among the worker tasks (right now I find the worker with the shortest queue, and enqueue the item to it).

What would be a good pattern or technique to use to make some intelligent decisions as to how many workers I should spin up to handle the items?  This logic would need to include shutting workers down if the items are able to be processed in a timely fashion by less workers.

I realize that adding more workers won't scale infinitely as ultimately other resources will be bottlenecked, and at some point adding more workers will hurt more than help.  If I could account for this, and decide to scale DOWN the number of workers to find the 'sweet spot' automatically, that would be fantastic, however at this point I'd be happy if my system could just increase the number of workers as more items are added, and then decrease the number as less items are needed.

One idea I've toyed around with is measuring the average time an item sits in the queue.  If this average time is greater than a couple seconds, I should spin up more workers (until the set max limit is reached).  If the average time is less than 1 second, I should spin down more workers (until there's only one left of course).

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to scale unless you can break the work down into chunks that can be distributed amongst workers.  How you distribute that work really depends on how you break down the work.  If you break down the work into smaller chunks whose results get merged when done, then the map/reduce pattern may fit the bill...

One thing to keep in mind, regardless of what you do, is that as soon as you have more threads running than CPUs your performance will degrade dramatically.  this is because you increase/introduce context switching which is very expensive.  Using things like TPL and PLINQ will allow you to schedule tasks and avoid this problem.

Comment: The work in this case, is chunks that can be distributed... The work is actually sending messages to Apple Push notification services, google C2DM, and windows phone notifications.  In the case of apple, each worker keeps a connection to apple's servers and sends messages, which is why doing it in parallel will help scale (to some extent).

Answer (score 0):

You could also compute a global running average of number of queued task per seconds, and divide by maximum task per seconds one worker can process. This will give you the number of worker you need to not fall behind.

You also want to introduce a delay, (if for x seconds there is less worker then needed increase) (if for x seconds there is more worker then needed decrease).

This assume all task take the same amount of time to process and that all your worker have the same throughput.